# cmd batch search csv using wilcard

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, copy, wildcard

I have a CSV file which I have exported from our data module, which only contain product numbers. The product numbers are comma separated, which may or may not course a problem (I am not that good of a programmer). I found a fancy little batch here at stackoverflow, which has helped me to read the csv when running the batch, however, I am lost when it comes to trigger the right commands.

```
@echo off
set "theDir=C:\Web\Photos"
for /F "delims=" %%x in (C:\Web\MySQL_active_product_numbers.csv) do (
   copy %theDir%\%%x*.* "C:\Web\ActivePhotos\"
)
```

I have set the directory I want to scan, using the theDir variable, and in my csv file I have a list a product numbers. Example of csv content (one column only):

```
10000,02,65
10000,25,65
10001,02,65
...
```

The files I want to copy contain more characters than what each line in the csv contain, which is why I need the wildcard search to locate and copy the file. Example of files.

```
10000,02,65 chocolate bar.jpg
10000,25,65 ice cream cone.jpg
10001,02,65 candy.jpg
....
```

I really want to copy the jpgs from one directory to another, but as you can see from my csv, I only have the product numbers to match the filename, but I can't figure out how to use the wilcard search within my batch, to loop through the csv, to locate each file and copy it to a different directory. I hope it all made sense, and I appreciate all your input and support with my batch problem. Thanks.

Comment: just to clarify: your filenames look like "`10000,02,65 chocolate bar.jpg`"?

Comment: Yes Stephan, you are right, but I don't know the whole filename, I just know a fraction, which is the product number given to me in the csv. I then need to scan the directories to find a match for that product number within the filename(s). I hope it made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
copy %theDir%\%%x*.* "C:\Web\ActivePhotos\"
```

try:

```
copy "%theDir%\%%x*.*" "C:\Web\ActivePhotos\*.*"
```

(your filename contains spaces!)

**EDIT**
well, it runs well at my computer. The problem with commas and spaces can easilybe solved by enclosing `path\filename`in Doubleqoutes (`"`)  Here is the proof:

```
C:\Users\Stephan\CanCan>type t.bat
@echo off
dir C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\New\*.*

set "theDir=C:\users\Stephan\CanCan"
for /F "delims=" %%x in (C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\t.csv) do (
   copy "%theDir%\%%x*.*" "C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\New\*.*"
)

dir C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\New\*.*

C:\Users\Stephan\CanCan>type t.csv
10000,02,65
10000,25,65
10001,02,65
C:\Users\Stephan\CanCan>
C:\Users\Stephan\CanCan>dir *.jpg
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Boot
 Volumeseriennummer: FA25-2E12

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\Stephan\CanCan

01.08.2013  18:45                 6 10000,02,65 chocolate bar.jpg
01.08.2013  18:45                 6 10000,25,65 ice cream cone.jpg
01.08.2013  18:45                 6 10001,02,65 candy.jpg
               3 Datei(en),             18 Bytes
               0 Verzeichnis(se), 753.621.913.600 Bytes frei

C:\Users\Stephan\CanCan>t.bat
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Boot
 Volumeseriennummer: FA25-2E12

 Verzeichnis von C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\New

01.08.2013  18:52    <DIR>          .
01.08.2013  18:52    <DIR>          ..
               0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 753.621.913.600 Bytes frei
C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\10000,02,65 chocolate bar.jpg
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\10000,25,65 ice cream cone.jpg
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\10001,02,65 candy.jpg
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Boot
 Volumeseriennummer: FA25-2E12

 Verzeichnis von C:\users\Stephan\CanCan\New

01.08.2013  18:53    <DIR>          .
01.08.2013  18:53    <DIR>          ..
01.08.2013  18:45                 6 10000,02,65 chocolate bar.jpg
01.08.2013  18:45                 6 10000,25,65 ice cream cone.jpg
01.08.2013  18:45                 6 10001,02,65 candy.jpg
               3 Datei(en),             18 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 753.621.913.600 Bytes frei


C:\Users\Stephan\CanCan>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply here Stephan, and sadly yes, nearly all file names contain spaces, which is why I need to tidy all this up. But first I need to find all the active photos using my csv list. Sadly I have taken over from a person, who does not understand the misuse of white spaces, or adding commas in file names for that matter. I tried your suggestion but it just keep telling me the file doesn't exist, but I appreciate your reply and your time.

Comment: Are the paths and the CSV filename the same as in your hard drive?  You will get errors in certain cases and we need to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question foxidrive, but I will try to explain as best as possible.

theDir=C:\Web\Photos  //Is where the jpgs are located (and also within subdirectiories)

C:\Web\MySQL_active_product_numbers.csv  //Contain all the product numbers in a single column.

This is what the csv look like:

10000,02,65
10000,25,65
10001,02,65

This is what the file names look like:

10000,02,65 chocolate bar.jpg
10000,25,65 ice cream cone.jpg
10001,02,65 candy.jpg

I am looping through the csv, and trying to locate a file name that matches i.e. 10000,02,65. I hope it make sense.

Comment: I am not sure what I did wrong Stephan, but it works like a charm now - YOU ARE A LIFESAVER :-) Thanks a lot for your help :-)